# QueueManager is not connecting given Exception : MQJE001:

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I written a Java MQ client to write and read message after went to multiple sites learned a bit about MQ.  When I run the client code it given error as below:

```
        MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2540'.
```

I put a log statement in and it shows Exception in the below place

```
private void selectQMgr() throws MQException {
    logger.info("qMgrName in selectQMgr method: "+ qMgrName);       
    qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qMgrName, mqht);
```

mqht is Hashtable reference which contains the Host Name,Port and channel propery which I passed from script.

My system has v 7.5 MQ client and I used all the required jars for compile and run.

Also I went to /opt/mqm/samp/bin and run the below command

```
     •  $ amqsput TESTQ QMGR
     •  Sample AMQSPUT0 start
     •  MQCONN ended with reason code 2058
     •  $ MQCONN ended with reason code 2058
```

it given above error not sure whether I am trying correct or not.

I am new to MQ and bit confused after I read from the IBM site mentioned as below:
       •    Queue-manager groups are not supported.
       •    There is no queue-manager group with the specified name.

All the Required properties for MQ connection got from Support team not sure what is the issue. Is it  my system not connecting or not.

Please help on this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: 2540 is `MQRC_UNKNOWN_CHANNEL_NAME`. You also mention a Hasttable reference which contains the Host name, port and channel properties. Have you confirmed that the channel name in there is corret and that SVRCONN channel exists on the queue manager you are connecting to?

With regards to the amqsput error. 2058 means `MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR` if the Queue Manager "QMGR" doesn't exist on your local machine then that will be what is causing that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 types of connection models:

1. Bindings mode - when an application connects to a queue manager in bindings mode, the application MUST be running on the same server as the queue manager.  The application also does NOT specify the host, port # and channel name.
2. Client mode - means that the application MUST specify the host, port # and channel name because the application is NOT on the same server as the queue manager.

> $ amqsput TESTQ QMGR

IBM has a naming standard for executable files:

1. If the executable file does NOT end with 'c' (i.e. amqsput) then it is is compiled and linked for bindings mode.  i.e. local queue manager
2. If the executable file DOES end with 'c' (i.e. amqsputc) then it is is compiled and linked for client mode.  Hence, you need to use either a CCDT file by setting [MQCHLLIB & MQCHLTAB](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016950_.htm) environment variables or set the [MQSERVER](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016990_.htm) environment variable.

Now on the remote server, there can be 1 or more queue managers running.  Each queue manager will have its own MQ listener listening on a port. i.e. 1414.  If there are 3 queue managers running on the server then the ports used could be 1414, 1415 & 1416 or 14001, 14002 & 14003.  You will need to ask your MQAdmin for the correct port number for that particular queue manager.

Reason Code of 2540 (MQRC_UNKNOWN_CHANNEL_NAME) means that you are using a channel name that is NOT defined on the queue manager.  Note: All objects are case sensitive.  i.e. "Test.Chl" is not the same as "TEST.CHL".  Also, bookmark the [MQ Reason Code](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q040710_.htm) page because it is something you will need to reference often.

Finally, since you are new to MQ, I would strongly suggest you attend [MQ Technical Conference](https://www.mqtechconference.com) (MQTC).  MQTC is the largest conference in the world solely dedicated to IBM MQ. It is 3 days of technical training at a super cheap price.

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot